# Accessing nth element of XML in PHP with SimpleXml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo id="1">
    <bar>text</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo id="2">
    <bar>text2</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

I know that, in PHP, you I can access the nth element of an xml file loaded with SimpleXML like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
echo $xml->foo[2]->bar;
```

but I need to access an element by a variable pulled from `$_GET`, so:

```
echo $xml->foo[$var]->bar;
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I'd really appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is in `$var`?

Comment: An integer. I'm passing it like this:
URL: "http://www.foo.com/bar.php?var=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems SimpleXML distinguishes between numeric and non-numeric array offsets in a slightly different way to a normal PHP array, so you need to cast your variable to an integer first. (All input from the query string is a string until you tell PHP otherwise.)

```
$var = intval($_GET['var']);
echo $xml->foo[$var]->bar;
```

This will turn the string `'1'` into the integer `1`, and should give the result you require.

Comment: @AmalMurali I didn't know either until I was playing around with a live sample and thought to try it. There are a few things like this where SimpleXML can't quite emulate the "deep magic" of core PHP functionality - another is that `$some_simple_xml_node * 1.0` does an implicit cast to `int`, not `float`, unlike `$some_string * 1.0`.