# PHP: Using $_GET["id"] to replace XML node

Tags: php, xml

I am using PHP and an external XML file to display an HTML page which allows a user to update an item's status using various form/input buttons.

The current format is that you can look at one HTML page with a master list of items and their status, then click on one to move to a new HTML page letting you specify the status of that item. So I can click on "Widget X", then see a new page (status.php?id=X), then click on a button labeled "ready", and PHP will use $_GET["id"] to find the relevant XML node and replace it's  attribute with "ready".

For some reason I absolutely cannot get PHP to use the data from $_GET to specify an XML node. Here is the current troubleshooting code:

```
<?php
    $idx = $_GET["id"]; /*Get id# from previous page*/
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml'); /*Load external .xml*/
    $array = array(100, 200, 300); /*Basic array for comparison*/

  print_r($xml); /*Display contents of test.xml*/
$xml->item[$idx]->status = 'waiting'; /*change item $idx's status to 'waiting'*/ 
echo '<br/>';
 print_r($xml); /*Display changed xml*/

  /*Display changed basic array values to confirm $idx has a value*/
  $array[$idx] = 123;
echo '<br/>';
  print_r($array);
  $array["$idx"] = 456;
echo '<br/>';
  print_r($array);
  $array["{$idx}"] = 789;
echo '<br/>';
  print_r($array);
?>
```

And here is the contents of test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<widgets>
    <item>
            <name>Widget X</name>
            <status>ready</status>
    </item>
    <item>
            <name>Widget Z</name>
            <status>waiting</status>
    </item>
</widgets>
```

The basic array has no problem using $idx = $_GET["id"]; to choose which array element to change. But $xml->item[$idx]->status does not work. If, however, I change to $idx = 0, then $xml->item[$idx]->status does work.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something about how $_GET or SimpleXML works?

Comment: Dont use $xml->[array] you need think out side of the box, and reach the solution therefore, the complexity of studies completed is an opening to improve the development of guidelines for the future. Can you think about it? use $_POST[array]

Answer (score 0):

[Accessing nth element of XML in PHP with SimpleXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689295/accessing-nth-element-of-xml-in-php-with-simplexml)

> It seems SimpleXML distinguishes between numeric and non-numeric array
>   offsets in a slightly different way to a normal PHP array, so you need
>   to cast your variable to an integer first. (All input from the query
>   string is a string until you tell PHP otherwise.)
>
> $var = intval($_GET['var']); echo $xml->foo[$var]->bar; This will turn
>   the string '1' into the integer 1, and should give the result you
>   require.