# Accessing nth element of XML with different node names in PHP with SimpleXml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When all the children of an XML node have the same name, using SimpleXml in PHP you can access the nth element easily with $xml->foo[$nth].
( [Accessing nth element of XML in PHP with SimpleXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689295/accessing-nth-element-of-xml-in-php-with-simplexml) )
How can I get the nth element if children have different names?

For example in an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo id="11" />
  <foo id="2" />
  <bar id="10" />
  <foo id="8" />
</root>
```

I'd like to know if the third element is a 'foo' or a 'bar' without iterating all the nodes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `children()` method:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$childrens = $xml->children();
var_dump($childrens[1]); // <foo id="2" />
var_dump($childrens[2]); // <bar id="10" />
```

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Comment: This is not working for me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: Probably you are using old php version. Updated my answer

Comment: Correct. Old php version. The edit is working. Thanks